# How to add popovers tooltip in tagsinput?

Tags: bootstrap-tags-input

I am trying to add popovers tooltip in tagsinput text field. But its not working.
Here is my code:

```
<div class="form-group"><!-- form-group -->
    <div class="col-lg-6" id="prefix_value_div_error" style="display:none">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'prefix_value', array('class'=>'col-lg-4 control-label')); ?>
        <div class="col-lg-7">
            <?php echo $form->textField($model,'prefix_value',array('class'=>'form-control tagsinput popovers','id'=>'prefix_value',"data-placement"=>"top","data-content"=>Yii::t('app','model.callThresholdPlanMaster.prefix_value.desc') ,"data-trigger"=>"hover", "data-original-title"=>Yii::t('app','model.callThresholdPlanMaster.prefix_value'))); ?>                  
            <div id="prefix_value_error">
                <?php echo $form->error($model,'prefix_value'); ?>
            </div>
        </div>   
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you found the solution for this?